# (Resolved) Quaternion1 step rotation to Quaternion2

Tags: python, scripting, quaternion

So I have an object that I want to rotate step by step to match another object rotation, at first not knowing any better i did like so..: 
Step=0.1 Q1=Q1-(Q1-Q2)Step .
What should be the formula? :p

Comment: And its odd how one asks a question and then soon after finds something similar even if prior one was looking for an answer in the same channels xD
https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/158037/rotate-objects-mesh-so-it-matches-another-objects-rotation

Comment: I seems you're looking for [SLERP](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/mathutils.html#mathutils.Quaternion.slerp)?

Comment: most likely, gonna look it up now, tho if one could write down the template/code of the wanted operation it would be appreciated.